# Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I installed Google analytics on my localhost and I am able to see the activities of the visitors on the real-time beta part but I am not able to see any report on the standard report part . Also on my account "The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page" is shown.

Where is the problem here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check whether you have put the Script which is given by the Google Analytics inside the header tag of the homepage

Comment: The code must be working and that's why I still able to see real-time visitors.

Comment: Hope thid will help you
http://groups.google.com/group/analytics-help-integrations/browse_thread/thread/3c710dd298395d0c?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

The "detection" mechanism crawls your site to see if it can find the code. It's a courtesy feature, applicable to very basic usages only.

But, it can't access your `localhost` (since its not available to its crawlers; it's trying to crawl whatever domain you have configured as your account's domain.

The regular reporting in GA is not in real time. It might take some time. Assuming you haven't manually set any incorrectly configured profiles, if your data is appearing in Real Time, it will eventually show up in Standard Reporting.

PS: Be sure to set the date selector to today's date; by default, GA shows data from 30 days ago until yesterday.